# List of channels disappeared in the graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

At some point, I think during the baking of actions, the channel names list disappeared from the graph editor.

In the attached image you can see I am in pose mode and I have selected a bone in the armature. I have the "only show selected" option enabled so I can work with only the channels of that bone. The correct curves appear in the graph editor, but there is nothing in the list of channels to the left!

[image]

How can I get this list back, I have tried everything I can think of. If I uncheck the "only show selected" option all curves of all bones appear and the channel list also appears, but this is very hard to work with. I'd like the "only show selected" option to work.

Things I've tried: adding new keyframes for this bone, ALT+H to unhide everything, installing a newer Blender version.

Comment: Same question was just posted by someone else and they found the answer. :) (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298240/animation-graph-editor-how-can-i-get-my-channels-back-for-the-selected-objec) I had unknowingly clicked on the "disable selection" option on the armature in the Outliner window.